# error: request for member '..' in '..' which is of non-class type

Tags: c++

I have a class with two constructors, one that takes no arguments and one that takes one argument.

Creating objects using the constructor that takes one argument works as expected. However, if I create objects using the constructor that takes no arguments, I get an error.

For instance, if I compile this code (using g++ 4.0.1)...

```
class Foo
{
  public:
    Foo() {};
    Foo(int a) {};
    void bar() {};
};

int main()
{
  // this works...
  Foo foo1(1);
  foo1.bar();

  // this does not...
  Foo foo2();
  foo2.bar();

  return 0;
}
```

... I get the following error:

```
nonclass.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, const char**)’:
nonclass.cpp:17: error: request for member ‘bar’ in ‘foo2’, which is of non-class type ‘Foo ()()’
```

Why is this, and how do I make it work?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2318650/69537

Answer (score 840, accepted):

```
Foo foo2();
```

change to

```
Foo foo2;
```

You get the error because compiler thinks of

```
Foo foo2()
```

as of function declaration with name 'foo2' and the return type 'Foo'.

But in that case If we change to `Foo foo2` , the compiler might show the error   `" call of overloaded ‘Foo()’ is ambiguous"`.

Comment: I don't understand why the compiler thinks : Foo foo2() as of function declaration, inside the main function.

Comment: Apparently I've landed on this answer before since I can not upvote it again! Here is a textual 2nd upvote... and a 2nd thanks!

Comment: Parameterless function declaration should have mandated "void" parameter so that this usage would have been allowed from consistency point of view. If I am not mistaken, K&R C had mandatory usage of term void.

Comment: @Rajesh: A void parameter list is not mandatory, it just means something different (zero parameters) from an empty parameter list (unspecified parameters).

Comment: this is another good reason to switch to [uniform {} initialization syntax](http://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/initialization) introduces in c++11

Answer (score 42):

Just for the record..

It is actually not a solution to your code, but I had the same error message when incorrectly accessing the method of a class instance pointed to by `myPointerToClass`, e.g.

```
MyClass* myPointerToClass = new MyClass();
myPointerToClass.aMethodOfThatClass();
```

where

```
myPointerToClass->aMethodOfThatClass();
```

would obviously be correct.

Answer (score 16):

Parenthesis is not required to instantiate a class object when you don't intend to use a parameterised constructor.

Just use  **Foo foo2;**

It will work.

Answer (score 10):

Adding to the knowledge base, I got the same error for

```
if(class_iter->num == *int_iter)
```

Even though the IDE gave me the correct members for class_iter. Obviously, the problem is that `"anything"::iterator` doesn't have a member called `num` so I need to dereference it. Which doesn't work like this:

```
if(*class_iter->num == *int_iter)
```

...apparently. I eventually solved it with this:

```
if((*class_iter)->num == *int_iter)
```

I hope this helps someone who runs across this question the way I did.

Answer (score 7):

I was having a similar error, it seems that the compiler misunderstand the call to the constructor without arguments. I made it work by removing the parenthesis from the variable declaration, in your code something like this:

```
class Foo
{
  public:
    Foo() {};
    Foo(int a) {};
    void bar() {};
};

int main()
{
  // this works...
  Foo foo1(1);
  foo1.bar();

  // this does not...
  Foo foo2; // Without "()" 
  foo2.bar();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is the same answer as [the one above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/877523/error-request-for-member-in-which-is-of-non-class-type#answer-877538)

Comment: The [most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse) isn't so much that the compiler misunderstood, as it is that the standard _requires_ the compiler to interpret anything that might be a function declaration as a function declaration, to prevent ambiguity.

Comment: (Specifically, between [`[stmt.ambig/1]`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/stmt.ambig#1) and [`[dcl.ambig.res/1]`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/dcl.ambig.res#1), the standard explicitly states that in case of ambiguity, anything that can be interpreted as a declaration IS a declaration, to resolve that ambiguity.)

Answer (score 4):

I ran into a case where I got that error message and had

```
Foo foo(Bar());
```

and was basically trying to pass in a temporary Bar object to the Foo constructor. Turns out the compiler was translating this to

```
Foo foo(Bar(*)());
```

that is, a function declaration whose name is foo that returns a Foo that takes in an argument -- a function pointer returning a Bar with 0 arguments. When passing in temporaries like this, better to use `Bar{}` instead of `Bar()` to eliminate ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to declare a new substance with no parameter (knowing that the object have default parameters) don't write

```
 type substance1();
```

but

```
 type substance;
```

Answer (score 1):

Certainly a corner case for this error, but I received it in a different situation, when attempting to overload the assignment `operator=`.  It was a bit cryptic IMO (from g++ 8.1.1).

```
#include <cstdint>

enum DataType
{
  DT_INT32,
  DT_FLOAT
};

struct PrimitiveData
{
  union MyData
  {
    int32_t i;
    float f;
  } data;

  enum DataType dt;

  template<typename T>
  void operator=(T data)
  {
    switch(dt)
    {
      case DT_INT32:
      {
        data.i = data;
        break;
      }
      case DT_FLOAT:
      {
        data.f = data;
        break;
      }
      default:
      {
        break;
      }
    }
  }
};

int main()
{
  struct PrimitiveData pd;
  pd.dt = DT_FLOAT;
  pd = 3.4f;

  return 0;
}
```

I received 2 "identical" errors

```
error: request for member ‘i’ [and 'f'] in ‘data’, which is of non-class type ‘float’
```

(The equivalent error for `clang` is:
`error: member reference base type 'float' is not a structure or union`)

for the lines `data.i = data;` and `data.f = data;`.  Turns out the compiler was confusing local variable name 'data' and my member variable `data`.  When I changed this to `void operator=(T newData)` and `data.i = newData;`, `data.f = newData;`, the error went away.

Answer (score 0):

@MykolaGolubyev has already given wonderful explanation. I was looking for a solution to do somthing like this `MyClass obj ( MyAnotherClass() )` but the compiler was interpreting it as a function declaration.

C++11 has [braced-init-list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization). Using this we can do something like this

```
Temp t{String()};
```

However, this:

```
Temp t(String());
```

throws compilation error as it considers `t` as of type `Temp(String (*)())`.

```
#include <iostream>

class String {
public:
    String(const char* str): ptr(str)
    {
        std::cout << "Constructor: " << str << std::endl;
    }
    String(void): ptr(nullptr)
    {
        std::cout << "Constructor" << std::endl;
    }
    virtual ~String(void)
    {
        std::cout << "Destructor" << std::endl;
    }

private:
    const char *ptr;
};

class Temp {
public:
    Temp(String in): str(in)
    {
        std::cout << "Temp Constructor" << std::endl;
    }

    Temp(): str(String("hello"))
    {
        std::cout << "Temp Constructor: 2" << std::endl;
    }
    virtual ~Temp(void)
    {
        std::cout << "Temp Destructor" << std::endl;
    }

    virtual String get_str()
    {
        return str;
    }

private:
    String str;
};

int main(void)
{
    Temp t{String()}; // Compiles Success!
    // Temp t(String()); // Doesn't compile. Considers "t" as of type: Temp(String (*)())
    t.get_str(); // dummy statement just to check if we are able to access the member
    return 0;
}
```