# C++ constructor behavior

Tags: c++, constructor

I'm declaring an instance of a class like so:

```
Matrix m;
```

This appears to implicitly initialize m (i.e. run the constructor).  Is this actually the case?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, the default constructor is called.

If there is no default constructor, this statement is ill-formed.  If there are no user-declared constructors, the compiler provides a default constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it creates an instance of class `Matrix` on the stack. This instance is intialized using the default constructor of class `Matrix`. This instance created on stack will be destroyed when the variable `m` goes out of scope. When the object is destroyed its destructor will be called.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, syntactically this is equal to writing:

```
Matrix m();
```

Although, if there is no default constructor defined the compiler will give an error.

NOTE: If no constructors are defined for a class a default constructor is made by the compiler, but if a constructor with parameters is defined the default constructor is NOT made by the compiler.

Comment: It is not syntactically equal to writing that.  That declares a function named `m` that takes no parameters and returns a `Matrix`.

Comment: You might see this question about this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318650/is-no-parentheses-on-a-c-constructor-with-no-arguments-a-language-standard

Comment: My mistake. When using 'new' you can choose to add the '()' or not.