# C++ strings connecting with char arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, string, char

Is this good way to do it?

```
char* array = "blah blah";
char* array2 = "bloh bloh";
string str = string() + array + array2;
```

Can't do direct `string str = array + array2`, can't add 2 pointers. Or should I do this

```
string str();
str += array;
str += array2;
```

Comment: no, mixing low-level and high level types is not good.

Comment: By the way, this code isn’t valid C++ any more (with C++11), and should generate warnings even when using older C++ for the use of deprecated non-const `char*` literals. Furthermore, the second code doesn’t compile anyway due to the [most vexing parse](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1424510/1968).

Comment: @usoban: There is a reason that `std::string` defines a conversion from `char*` to `std::string`.  Sometimes you have a `char*` to deal with and there's no way around it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would write:

```
string str = string(array) + array2;
```

Note that your second version [is not valid code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318650/is-no-parentheses-on-a-c-constructor-with-no-arguments-a-language-standard). You should remove the parentheses:

```
string str;
str += array;
str += array2;
```

Lastly, `array` and `array2` should be of type **`const`**`char *`.

Comment: @user1112008: I am not sure I understand your question.

Comment: I just need to glue 2(or more) char arrays to string.

Answer (score 3):

There are lots of ways to do this:

```
string str(array);
str += array2;
```

or

```
string str = string(array) + array2;
```

or even

```
string str = array + string(array2);
```

or string streams:

```
stringstream ss;
ss << array << array2;
```