# Why is Wizard wiz0; not equivalent to Wizard wiz0(); in my code? C2228 Error

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, visual-c++-2010-express

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is no parentheses on a constructor with no arguments a language standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318650/is-no-parentheses-on-a-constructor-with-no-arguments-a-language-standard)

Okay, I've got a pickle. It's an error C2228 issue, and I've looked at other questions and answers, and none of the tips given seem to work for me- this is my first question, and I'm a newbie, so please be gentle! Note: The program WILL compile if I use

```
Wizard wiz0;
```

but NOT if I use

```
Wizard wiz0();
```

The book I am using tells me that these two statements should be equivalent, so I am trying to figure out why I can use one and not the other.

First off, here is the error when I attempt to use Wizard wiz0():

```
1>  Chapter5.cpp
1>Chapter5.cpp(14): error C2228: left of '.fight' must have class/struct/union
1>Chapter5.cpp(15): error C2228: left of '.talk' must have class/struct/union
1>Chapter5.cpp(17): error C2228: left of '.setArmor' must have class/struct/union
1>Chapter5.cpp(19): error C2228: left of '.getName' must have class/struct/union
1>Chapter5.cpp(21): error C2228: left of '.castSpell' must have class/struct/union
```

Here is (what I think) the relevant code from Chapter5.cpp is:

```
Wizard wiz0(); //declares a variable (wiz0) of type Wizard.

wiz0.fight();
wiz0.talk();

wiz0.setArmor(10);

cout << "Player's Name: " << wiz0.getName() << endl;

wiz0.castSpell();
```

Also, here is the information from wiz.h file:

```
public
//Constructor
Wizard();

//Overloaded Constructor
Wizard(std::string name, int hp, int mp, int armor);

//Destructor
~Wizard();

//Methods
void fight();
void talk();
void castSpell();
void setArmor(int mArmor);
std::string Wizard::getName();

private:
//Data members
std::string mName;
int mHitPoints;
int mMagicPoints;
int mArmor;
```

...and finally, information from the wiz.cpp file!

```
//Wiz.cpp implementation file

#include "stdAfx.h"
#include "wiz.h"
using namespace std;

//The Constructor call
Wizard::Wizard()
{
/*If the client calls a constructor without
specifying values, these will be the default
values that the program will use */
mName = "DefaultName";
mHitPoints = 1;
mMagicPoints = 1;
mArmor = 0;
}

Wizard::Wizard(std::string name, int hp, int mp, int armor)
{
//Client called constructor WITH values, so create an
//object with them.
mName = name;
mHitPoints = hp;
mMagicPoints = mp;
mArmor = armor;
}

void Wizard::fight()
{
    cout << "Fighting." << endl;
}

void Wizard::talk()
{
    cout << "Talking." << endl;
}

void Wizard::castSpell()
{
    if (mMagicPoints < 4)
        cout << "Casting spell." << endl;
    else
        cout << "Not enough MP!" << endl;
}

void Wizard::setArmor(int armor)
{
    if(armor >= 0)
        mArmor = armor;
} 

std::string Wizard::getName()
{
return mName;
}

Wizard::~Wizard()
{
//Not using dynamic memory- nothing to clean
}
```

Phew... I think that's everything. If you guys can figure out what it is I'm doing wrong, I'd greatly appreciate it!

Comment: `Wizard wiz0();` is a function declaration.

Comment: Either you misread the book, or it is time to look for a better one. The two statements (in that context) are **not** equivalent.

Comment: Do not meddle in the affairs of wizards, for they are subtle and [most vexing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2318650/1593077).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a weird part of the way C++ is parsed. The one with parentheses is interpreted as a function prototype. You should use the one without the parentheses.

Comment: So the book telling me that they are equivalent is incorrect?

Comment: Yes. If that's what it says, it's incorrect.

Comment: @user1759305: What does your book say exactly ?

Comment: In some contexts they can be similar. In the context you used them they are different. What is the book and what does it say?

Comment: "Constructors are called when the object is created. Thus, instead of writing:

    Wizard wiz0;

we now write:

 Wizard wiz0(); // use default constructor

or we can specify in-line, like so:

Wizard wiz0("Gandalf", 20, 50, 5) // use overloaded constructor

Comment: That didn't space very well, but I think you can get the idea. >.>

Comment: OK, book is completely wrong.

Comment: Ah, okay! THank you, guys! I can't give upvotes yet, but when I can I'll come back and upvote you all!

Comment: Found the book, http://www.scribd.com/doc/42407078/C-Module-I For a very quick look it seems to be reasonable quality. Probably just a one-off error then.

Answer (score 6):

```
Wizard wiz0;
```

instantiates a `Wizard` object called `wiz0`

```
Wizard wiz0();
```

declares a function `wiz0` returning a `Wizard` by value. This is a simplified version of the [most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

Comment: Thank you for your input. The book tells me that these two snippets are identical- I suppose the book goofed?

Comment: @user1759305 it looks like a mistake in the book. Which book is it, by the way?

Comment: "C++ Programming, Module I" Gameinstitute.com, e-Institute Publishing.

Comment: Thank you again for your help- when I have 15 rep I'll come back and upvote you! :)