# .txt to vector <string>, non-class type error

Tags: c++

Hi I just started to learn C++ this week and I require some assistance. 
Basically what I am trying to do is read from a .txt file and "convert" it into a vector string and then display it.
my error is at this line: text.readFile("scenario.txt"), it says: "request for member 'readFile' in 'text', which is of non-class type 'Conversion()'" 
what does that mean?
and also my method getLines() could not be resolved.

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include "Conversion.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<string> lines;

    Conversion text();

    if(text.readFile("scenario.txt") == true)
        lines = text.getLines();

    for(int i = 0; i < lines.size(); ++i)
        cout << lines[i] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Conversion.cpp

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include "Conversion.h"

using namespace std;
vector<string> lines;

Conversion::Conversion(std::vector<std::string> lines) {
    lines.clear();
}
Conversion::Conversion() {
}

Conversion::~Conversion() {
}

bool Conversion::readFile(string filename) {
    ifstream file;
    string line;

    file.open(filename.c_str());

    if(!file.is_open())
        return false;

    while(getline(file, line))
        lines.push_back(line);

    return true;
}

vector<string> Conversion::getLines(){
    return lines;
}
```

Conversion.h

```
#ifndef CONVERSION_H_
#define CONVERSION_H_

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

class Conversion {
public:
    Conversion();
    Conversion(std::vector <std::string>);
    ~Conversion();
    std::vector<std::string> getLines();
    bool readFile(std::string);

private:
    std::vector<std::string> lines;
    std::string line;
    std::ifstream file;
};

#endif
```

Comment: C++ is pass-by-value. `lines.clear();` is going to do nothing. If you meant to use the global (which should really not be declared as a global at all considering you have one as a member), you're going to have to change one of the names or access it differently. Even then, taking a parameter and not using it seems pointless, and the member is already clear, so there's no need to clear it again.

Comment: Yep I took it off. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once again, `Conversion text();` is a function declaration, not a class instantiation. To call the default constructor, change it to `Conversion text;`

You probably wanted to copy the passed lines in your constructor:

```
Conversion::Conversion(std::vector<std::string> const& lines) : lines(lines) { }
```

Your code should work now, but there can be done some improvements. To avoid copy, `getLines` should return by reference-to-const:

```
std::vector<std::string> const& getLines();

// you don't have to create lines in main, you can print like this:

for(auto const& x : text.getLines())
    cout << x << endl;
```

and I'd use it even here:

```
bool readFile(std::string const&);
```

I hope this is the last thing - `std::ifstream` constructor and `open` function also take `std::string`:

```
file.open(filename);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. yup that fixed the error at 'text.readFile("scenario.txt")' 
Now i just need to fix the error on 'lines = text.getLines();' which tells me "undefined reference to `Conversion::getLines()'"

Comment: @KH17 You had probably added `const&` qualifier only to function declaration and not definition or vice-versa.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the parentheses when instantiating the `Conversion` object:

```
Conversion text;
```

See this question for detailed answers: [Is no parentheses on a constructor with no arguments a language standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318650/is-no-parentheses-on-a-constructor-with-no-arguments-a-language-standard)