# Cannot figure out how to call parent constructor in c++

Tags: c++, inheritance

I am having issues calling a parent constructor from an inherited class.

Here is how I am trying to call the function:

```
pFile = fopen(filePath.c_str(), "r");
if (pFile == NULL) {
    std::cout << "Error opening file" << std::endl;
}

StatusObj status();

Subclass mcrf_(pFile, status);
```

and here is the subclass definition

```
class Subclass : public Superclass {
public:
    Subclass(FILE * f_ptr, StatusObj status) : SuperClass(f_ptr, status) {}
};
```

the SuperClass's constructor looks like this:

```
SuperClass( FILE * input, StatusObj & status, uint64_t src_id=0 );
```

So at this point I think I am doing everything right, however when I try to compile I am getting the following error:

```
/main.cpp:152: error: no matching function for call to ‘SubClass(FILE*&, StatusObj (&)())’
/SubClass.h:23: note: candidates are: SubClass(FILE*, StatusObj)
```

I know I have a pointer or reference off somewhere - can anyone lend a hand and help me locate it?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using `stdio` in C++ code?

Comment: **[MCVE]** please, as usual.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is no parentheses on a constructor with no arguments a language standard?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318650/is-no-parentheses-on-a-constructor-with-no-arguments-a-language-standard)

Answer (score 2):

(Most) vexing parse for `StatusObj status();` which is a function declaration.

Use

```
StatusObj status;
```

or

```
StatusObj status{};
```

Comment: **NOT** a most vexing parse, though.

Comment: @SergeyA Inline function definition?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, MVP is traditionally reserved for the cases like `A a(B());`

Comment: @SergeyA Ah, I see. I think I never got the MVP issue up to it's end. But what would be the correct term? `StatusObj status();` is an _inline funciotn declaration_? (definition was merely a typo above).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I would simply say *a function declaration*, to avoid confusion with `inline` functions. MVP is not a standard term either, but *most* there relates to the complexity of the case - and nothing is complex about straightforward function declaration. (what else `A x();` could be after all?)