# Calling the default (AKA argument-less) constructor in the most compact way

Tags: c++, default-constructor, c++98

I have reviewed many Q&A, but I cannot find a certain answer to this question.

For a class like this:

```
class A {
     public:
     int i;
     inline A() : i() {}
};
```

In plain C++98, how do I guarantee to call the default (argument-less) constructor at declaration in the most compact way?

```
A a;       //Is this guaranteed to call the default (argument-less) constructor?

A b();     //This is not what I want, the compiler thinks it's a function declaration
           //http://stackoverflow.com/a/877538/2436175

A c = A(); //This I know it works
```

(For what it is worth, I have tried it [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=09c86df9d97b77c45905d3beaf0b7404-9ac5ce49fb3bb81c20db0c664e0c63a1), in this instance it worked but who knows which values were in the stack...)

Note: class A in the end will have to be more complicated of what shown in the example.

Comment: The first variant will always call the default constructor, or a constructor with only default arguments.

Comment: If a class has defined at least one constructor, you cannot create it without calling a constructor of some kind.

Comment: `A c{};` (in C++11) and `A c = A();` (in C++03) are technically performing value-initialization, which will call the default constructor if there is one or zero-initialize if there is not. This is ever so slightly different from default-initialization of a type with no default constructor, which does nothing.

Comment: @NeilKirk every class has a constructor - it might be auto-generated by the compiler, but it is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line 1) calls the default constructor (or a constructor with all default parameters as Joachim stated)

Line 2) as you noted - not a constructor call

Line 3) a construction and an assignment - so default constructor and copy constructor will be called (unless the compiler optimizes the copy construction away). As pointed out in the comments - if (with C++11), a move constructor is available, this will be called.

Comment: `=`, when used for initialization, is a call to the copy constructor, not the assignment operator.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: Actually, since the question is tagged as C++98, you're totally right. But beware, [this isn't the case any more in C++11](http://blog.smartbear.com/c-plus-plus/c11-tutorial-introducing-the-move-constructor-and-the-move-assignment-operator/), since a move constructor would be called per default!

Answer (score 1):

```
A a;       //Is this guaranteed to call the default constructor?
```

This is correct, it will call the default constructor (or a constructor with default values for all its arguments).

If you want to construct your objects like this you have to either provide a default constructor (constructor without parameters) or let the implementation synthesise one for you (for this to happen you cant define any constructor for your class).

Also, like others have stated in the comments, this will also work for PODs (plain old data structures).

For a struct to be considered POD it must not have virtual functions, base classes, non-static members that are private or protected, destructor or constructors.

Comment: Note that for some types (`int`, `double`,etc) the default constructor does not initialize memory.  Pods included.

Comment: If you don't provide any constructors and it is not a POD, a default constructor will be made for you.

Comment: Yes that is true, but if you implement one constructor, then the default constructor wont be synthesised.

Comment: @AngelCastillo May you could rephrase your answer? I understood just like Neil Kirk. Then your explanation shed some light