# Overloading Class Member Function

Tags: c++, overloading

I have overloaded a function `fn` as `fn(int,char)` & `fn(int&,char&)` as shown below:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


void fn(int a, char c);
void fn(int& a, char& c);

int main()
{
   int a=10;
   char c= 'c';



  cout << "Inside main()" << endl;
  cout << hex << "&a : " << &a << endl;
  cout << hex << "&c : " << (int *)&c << endl;

   static_cast<void(*) (int&, char&)> (fn)(a, c);

    return 0;
    }


void fn(int a, char c)
{
    int tempInt;
    char tempChar;
    cout << "\n\nInside Call By Value Function " << endl;
    cout << hex << "&a : " << &a << endl;
    cout << hex << "&c : " << (int *)&c << endl;
    cout << hex << "&tempInt : " << &tempInt << endl;
    cout << hex << "&tempChar : " << (int *)&tempChar << endl;
    }


void fn(int& a, char& c)
{

    cout << "\n\nInside Call By Reference Function " << endl;
    cout << hex << "*a : " << &a << endl;
    cout << hex << "*c : " << (int*) &c << endl;

    }
```

The resolution for call to `fn(int,char)` or `fn(int&,char&)` is made through cast `static_cast<void(*) (int&, char&)> (fn)(a, c);`

It gives output:

```
$ ./Overloading
Inside main()
&a : 0x22ac5c
&c : 0x22ac5b


Inside Call By Reference Function
*a : 0x22ac5c
*c : 0x22ac5b
```

Now when I put this in a class as below:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Test{
public:
void fn(int a, char c);
void fn(int& a, char& c);
};



int main()
{
   int a=10;
   char c= 'c';

  Test T();
  cout << "Inside main()" << endl;
  cout << hex << "&a : " << &a << endl;
  cout << hex << "&c : " << (int *)&c << endl;

   static_cast<void(*) (int&, char&)> (T.fn)(a, c);

    return 0;
    }


void Test::fn(int a, char c)
{
    int tempInt;
    char tempChar;
    cout << "\n\nInside Call By Value Function " << endl;
    cout << hex << "&a : " << &a << endl;
    cout << hex << "&c : " << (int *)&c << endl;
    cout << hex << "&tempInt : " << &tempInt << endl;
    cout << hex << "&tempChar : " << (int *)&tempChar << endl;
    }


void Test::fn(int& a, char& c)
{

    cout << "\n\nInside Call By Reference Function " << endl;
    cout << hex << "*a : " << &a << endl;
    cout << hex << "*c : " << (int*) &c << endl;

    }
```

I get below error:

```
$ g++ -Wall Overloading.cpp -o Overloading
Overloading.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
Overloading.cpp:23:42: error: request for member ‘fn’ in ‘T’, which is of non-class type ‘Test()’
```

How do I resolve this?
How to make a proper call for `T's fn(int&,char&)`

I guess in my code the expression `static_cast<void(*) (int&, char&)> (T.fn)(a, c);` is incorrect.

Please help.

Thanks

**EDIT:**

My mistake

editing `Test T()` to `Test T;`

gives error

```
$ g++ -Wall Overloading.cpp -o Overloading
Overloading.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
Overloading.cpp:23:44: error: invalid static_cast from type ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ to type ‘void (*)(int&, char&)’
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: `T` is no variable, `T` is function, that returns `Test` and receive nothing.

Second: function-pointer is not member-function-pointer. You should use this syntax

```
typedef void (Test::*function)(int&, char&);
function f = &Test::fn;
(T.*f)(a, c);
```

Comment: @GauravK what error? here will be called `fn(int&, char&)` it's not what you want?

Comment: .@Forever `$ g++ -Wall Overloading.cpp -o Overloading
Overloading.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
Overloading.cpp:24:3: error: ‘function’ was not declared in this scope
Overloading.cpp:24:12: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘f’
Overloading.cpp:27:40: error: ‘t’ was not declared in this scope
Overloading.cpp:27:42: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘(’ token
Overloading.cpp:27:44: error: ‘f’ was not declared in this scope
Overloading.cpp:18:8: warning: unused variable ‘T’ [-Wunused-variable]
`

Comment: .@Forever Above error with `int main()
{
   int a=10;
   char c= 'c';

  Test T;
  cout << "Inside main()" << endl;
  cout << hex << "&a : " << &a << endl;
  cout << hex << "&c : " << (int *)&c << endl;

  typedef void (Test::*fn)(int&, char&);
  function f = &Test::fn;


   static_cast<void(*) (int&, char&)> (t.(*f))(a, c);
  
    return 0;
    }`

Comment: .@ForEver I have shown above my `main()` , it gives the error mentioned in comment. Can you give me ,`main()` code?

Comment: int main() { int a=10; char c= 'c'; Test T; cout << "Inside main()" << endl; cout << hex << "&a : " << &a << endl; cout << hex << "&c : " << (int *)&c << endl; typedef void (Test::*function)(int&, char&); function f = &Test::fn; (T.*f)(a, c); return 0; }

Answer (score 0):

See [error: request for member '..' in '..' which is of non-class type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/877523/1017348): the problem is with `Test T();`, try ommiting the parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `Test T();`, you're saying that `T` is a function with return type `Test`. However no such thing exists in your code.

The solution is:

```
Test T;
```

Comment: `the compiler thinks T is a function with return type of Test` By definition, what the compiler thinks is true is true, so `T` _is_ a[n undefined] function with return type of `Test`.