# Can we overload Constructor based on reference parameter type?

Tags: c++, constructor, constructor-overloading

I know we can not overload constructors as below (Only difference is initialization list):

```
myClass(const INT& oInt,const STRING& oStr):I(oInt),STR(oStr){

        cout << "my Class Object Created with I : " << I << " STR : " << STR << endl;
}

myClass(const INT& oInt,const STRING& oStr){
        I=oInt;
        STR=oStr;
        cout << "my Class Object Created with I : " << I << " STR : " << STR << endl;
}
```

But suppose I want to overload my constructor as:

```
myClass(const INT& oInt,const STRING& oStr):I(oInt),STR(oStr);
myClass(const INT oInt,const STRING oStr);
```

i.e. based on different parameter type `one as reference type` the other `as normal type`

I am referring to my old question:
[Overloading Class Member Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19539327/overloading-class-member-function)

Can it be achieved?

My Code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class INT{
int i;
    public:

INT(int i=0):i(i){
        cout << "INT Class Object Created with i : " << i << endl;
}

~INT()
{
    cout << "INT Class Object Destructed with i :" << i << endl;
}

INT(const INT& I){
    i=I.i;
        cout << "INT Class Copy Constructor called for i : "<< i << endl;
}

INT& operator= (const INT& I){

    i=I.i;
        cout << "INT Assignment operator called for i : "<< i << endl;
    return *this;
}

friend ostream& operator << (ostream& os,const INT& I){
        os << I.i ;
    return os;
}

};



class STRING{

    string str;

    public:
STRING(string str=""):str(str){

    cout << "STRING Class Object Created with str : " << str << endl;
}
~STRING()
{
    cout << "STRING Class Object Destructed with str :" << str << endl;
}


STRING(const STRING& S){
    str=S.str;
        cout << "STRING Class Copy Constructor called for str : "<< str << endl;
}

STRING& operator= (const STRING& S){

    str=S.str;
        cout << "STRING Assignment operator called for str : "<< str << endl;
    return *this;
}

friend ostream& operator << (ostream& os,const STRING& S){
        os << S.str ;
    return os;
}

};


class myClass{

    INT I;
        STRING STR;
    public:

myClass(const INT& oInt,const STRING& oStr):I(oInt),STR(oStr){

    cout << "my Class Object Created with I : " << I << " STR : " << STR << endl;
}

myClass(const INT oInt,const STRING oStr){
        I=oInt;
    STR=oStr;
    cout << "my Class Object Created with I : " << I << " STR : " << STR << endl;
}



~myClass()
{

    cout << "my Class Object Destructed with I : " << I << " STR : " << STR << endl;

}

};





int main()
{

       INT iObj(5);
       STRING strObj("Alina Peterson");


      cout << "\n\n======================================================\n\n" << endl;

      myClass myObj(iObj,strObj);

      cout << "\n\n======================================================\n\n" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The error I am getting is:

```
$ g++ -g -Wall CPP.cpp -o CPP
CPP.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
CPP.cpp:116:32: error: call of overloaded ‘myClass(INT&, STRING&)’ is ambiguous
       myClass myObj(iObj,strObj);
                                ^
CPP.cpp:116:32: note: candidates are:
CPP.cpp:86:1: note: myClass::myClass(INT, STRING)
 myClass(const INT oInt,const STRING oStr){
 ^
CPP.cpp:81:1: note: myClass::myClass(const INT&, const STRING&)
 myClass(const INT& oInt,const STRING& oStr):I(oInt),STR(oStr){
 ^
```

How do I cast my constructor so that it can differentiate between the two versions of my overloaded constructor?

Comment: Compiler says no! ;) May be you could get off with typedefs, but I doubt so.

Comment: Typedefs don't make any difference to overload resolution.

Comment: What is it that you are trying to accomplish? If you want to enable C++11 "moving" instead of copying, use rvalue references (`Type&&`) and `std::forward`. Otherwise, I can't see any point to distinguishing between passing references and values to a constructor but maybe I'm not trying hard enough.

Comment: Use the [named constructor idiom](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/named-ctor-idiom.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can overload a constructor on `T const&` and `T` but the compiler can't choose the constructor resulting in a pair of uncallavle constructors: neither is better than the other for any of the viable arguments. Further, you can't explicitly choose the constructor: constructors aren't normal functions and you can't cast them. Thus, overloading a constructor on `T const&` and `T` is entirely useless . However, you *can* overload based on rvalueness: have one constructor take a `T const&` and the other take a `T&&`.

Maybe you should ask about *what* you want to achieve rather than how you try to achieve it...

Comment: I was exploring Constructors and Initialization lists. So such a thought came to my mind. Was not able to resolve myself so came here and asked

Answer (score 1):

Say you have two functions:

```
void foo(int const x) {}
void foo(int const& x) {}
```

When you call

```
foo(10);
```

the compiler cannot disambiguate between the two overloaded functions.

When you have:

```
void foo(int& x) {}
void foo(int const& x) {}
```

and make the same call, `foo(10);`, the compiler will, correctly, choose the second one.

What you have

```
myClass(const INT& oInt,const STRING& oStr);

myClass(const INT oInt,const STRING oStr);
```

is analogous to first pair of functions.

The question that you should ask yourself is what are the requirements that lead you to create such overloads. Are they real requirements? Unless your requirements are something out of the ordinary, you should be able to manage with only one of them.

Answer (score 0):

well to call

```
myClass(const STRING& oStr, const INT& oInt):I(oInt),STR(oStr) {}
```

you can do either of the following

```
INT iObj(5);
STRING strObj("Alina Peterson");

INT& x = iObj;
myClass myObj(x, strObj);
```

OR

```
myClass myObj(*(&iObj), strObj);
```

for the other constructor, I don't think you can call it, would always result in an error

Answer (score -1):

You can't get around the fact that you can't have two functions (constructors or otherwise) that take the same parameters.  If you do that, you're not overloading, you're just duplicating the function.  The compiler doesn't make a special exception for passing by reference instead of by value.

What you can do as a work-around is add in an extra unused parameter (like a bool) to the overloaded constructor.

Comment: Trying Overloading as `myClass(const INT& oInt,const STRING& oStr):I(oInt),STR(oStr);
myClass(const INT oInt,const STRING oStr);` Obviously the types of parameters are different..Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19539327/overloading-class-member-function