# expression must be modified lvalue

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, lvalue

```
class Base

{

  private:

    int _b;

  public:

    Base();

    Base(int b);

    virtual void display();

    //Assignment operator overload.

    Base& operator=(const Base&);

};

Base::Base()

{

    _b = 0;

}

Base::Base(int b)

{

    _b = b;

}

void Base::display()

{

    cout<<"base value := "<<_b<<endl;

}

Base& Base::operator=(const Base& ob)

{

    //Check for self-assignment.

    if(this != &ob)

    {

        this->_b = ob._b;

    }

    return *this;

}

class Derived : public Base

{

  private:

    int _d;

  public:

    Derived();

    Derived(int d);

    void display();

    //Assignment operator overload.

    Derived & operator=(const Derived& ob);

};

Derived::Derived() : Base()

{

    _d = 0;

}

Derived::Derived(int d) : Base(d)

{

    _d = d;

}

void Derived::display()

{

    cout<<"Derived value := "<<_d<<endl;

}

Derived & Derived::operator=(const Derived& ob)

{

    if(this != &ob)

    {

        this->_d = ob._d;

    }

    return *this;

}

int main()

{

    Derived d1(10),d2(),d3;

    //How d2 becomes lvalue and not d3 above.

    d2 = d1;//Error :: expression must be modified lvalue.

    //d2.display();

    d3 = d1;

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Did you look at the preview when you asked the question? As you can see, it is quite unreadable. Please fix the formatting.

Comment: `d2()` declares a function (taking no arguments and returning a `Derived`), beware.

Comment: Thanks I thought i will work with default constructor call.

Answer (score 1):

```
Derived d2();
```

is treated as function declaration. Do this :-

```
Derived d1(10),d2,d3;
d2 = d1;          /////ahaa it's working
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your 'd2()'. The statement d2() does not create a derived object called d2 like you think it does.  The correct options are:

```
Derived d2;
Derived d2 = Derived();
Derived d2(0); // or any other integer
```

The statement

```
Derived d2();
```

tells the compiler that you are defining a function which takes no arguments and returns the type Derived.

See here for a longer explanation:
[error: request for member '..' in '..' which is of non-class type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/877523/error-request-for-member-in-which-is-of-non-class-type)