# Request for member which is of non-class (struct inside a struct)

Tags: c++, struct

I've got a problem with getting data from a struct inside a struct. I was searching for an answer (also on  stackoverflow) but still I didin't found it and I don't know why it doesn't work.

```
 struct axis
     {
            double pY0, pY1, pY2,
                   Y0,Y1,Y2,Y3;
     };
 struct sensor 
    {
        struct axis X;
        struct axis Y;
        struct axis Z;
    };

struct sensor H;
```

I want to get or change data from struct **axis** which is inside **sensor**.

```
H.X.Y0 = 100.0;
```

And this error keeps coming up.

```
error: request for member 'X' in 'H', which is of non-class type 'double'
```

How to properly get data and why this methods is not working?

EDIT (My orginal code after your suggestions)

```
struct os
    {
        double pY0;
        double pY1;
        double pY2;
        double Y0;
        double Y1;
        double Y2;
        double Y3;
    };
struct czujnik 
{
    os X;
    os Y;
    os Z;
};
czujnik H1, H2, STJ1, STJ2;

H1.X.Y0 = 0; //Line 2018
H1.X.Y3 = H1.X.Y2;
H1.X.Y2 = H1.X.Y1;
H1.X.Y1 = H1.X.Y0;
H1.X.Y0 =(((double)adcRecv1[i-3]*a3+(double)adcRecv1[i-2]*a2+(double)adcRecv1[i-1]*a1+(double)adcRecv1[i]*a0-b3*H1.X.Y3-b2*H1.X.Y2-b1*H1.X.Y1)/b0);
            limitH=(((double)adcRecv1[i]*a3+(double)adcRecv1[i-1]*a2+(double)adcRecv1[i-2]*a1+(double)adcRecv1[i-3]*a0-b3*H1.X.Y0-b2*H1.X.Y1-b1*H1.X.Y2)/b0);
```

And errors:

```
2018|error: request for member 'X' in 'H1', which is of non-class type 'double'|
2019|error: request for member 'X' in 'H1', which is of non-class type 'double'|
...
```

Comment: Your code says `H`. Your error message says `H1`. Are you sure that's the actual line of code where the error is?

Comment: don't you want `H.X.Y0 = 100.0;`?

Comment: Yes. I;m sorry, I was simpyfing code for a purpose of a question and I forgot about his one.

Comment: The code you have posted does not give that error message, at least not with my compiler. Please post a minimal but _complete_ program that shows the problem. And don't forget to test that program first, so you know that the error is still there.

Comment: Take a look [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/877523/error-request-for-member-in-which-is-of-non-class-type9). Maybe it could drive you to understand the problem in your real code.

Comment: `H.X.Y0 = 100.0;` works fine here.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, @ThomasPadron-McCarthy suggest me a correct answer.

Comment: Ok, good that the problem is solved. But note that the updated version of the code is _still_ not a minimal _or_ a complete program _or_ one that shows the problem. It would have been so much easier if we'd had one from the beginning.

Comment: I was pretty long and I didn't thought that other parts of code would be useful for you. If I knew I would make it better. I just didn't wanted to make a mess. Anyway, I appreciate your help and patience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing your actual code, I am just guessing, but it seems likely that you have declared *another* variable called `H`, and that variable is of type `double`.

Comment: Oh, that was the problem! Thank you! I don't know why I forgot about this. I knew it must be trivial.