# Which constructor will be called?

Tags: c++, constructor

**Why there is no output?
Why doesn’t an ambiguity error occur?**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class A{
public:
    A(){
        cout << "Class A";
    }
    A(int a = 0){
        cout << "A";
    }
};

int main() {
    A a();
    return 0;
}
```

So when we create an object “a” of type “A”  `A a();`, compiler calls a constructor without parameters, doesn’t he?

> In C++, We can have more than one constructor in a class with same name, as long as each has a different list of arguments. A constructor is called depending upon the number and type of arguments passed.
>   While creating the object, arguments must be passed to let compiler know, which constructor needs to be called.

Comment: It doesn't... because you declared a function and not an object.

Comment: It's also often tied to this error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/877523/error-request-for-member-in-which-is-of-non-class-type